# Parsing regular expressions based on a context free grammar

Tags: java, regex, parsing

Good evening, Stack Overflow.
I'd like to develop an interpreter for expressions based on a pretty simple context-free grammar:

[Grammar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdHDT.png)

Basically, the language is constituted by 2 base statements

```
( SET var 25 ) // Output: var = 25
( GET ( MUL var 5 ) ) // Output: 125
( SET var2 ( MUL 30 5 ) ) //Output: var2 = 150
```

Now, I'm pretty sure about what should I do in order to interpret a statement: 1) Lexical analysis to turn a statement into a sequence of tokens 2) Syntax analysis to get a symbol table (HashMap with the variables and their values) and a syntactic tree (to perform the GET statements) to 3) perform an inorder visit of the tree to get the results I want.

I'd like some advice on the parsing method to read the source file. Considering the parser should ignore any whitespace, tabulation or newline, is it possible to use a Java Pattern to get a general statement I want to analyze? Is there a good way to read a statement weirdly formatted (and possibly more complex) like this

```
(
  SET var

 25
 )
```

without confusing the parser with the open and closed parenthesises?

For example

```
Scanner scan; //scanner reading the source file
String pattern = "..." //ideal pattern I've found to represent an expression
while(scan.hasNext(pattern))
  Interpreter.computeStatement(scan.next(pattern));
```

would it be a viable option for this problem?

Comment: after you read all the file content and store it in a string, then `for(string part: fileContent.split("\s+")){/* ... */}`. now `part` stores meaningful characters. notice that you still have to perform lexical analysis to `part`, but it's easy.

Comment: The default delimiter for `Scanner` is to match white space, so you're all set to go with out adding any special regex at all.

Comment: @markspace I'm aware that Scanner uses whitespace as delimiter, I was wondering how to make the Scanner recognise only one statement at once. Using Interpreter.computeStatement(scan.next()) should get only a token at once (a parenthesis, a keyword, a number or a variable)

Comment: The normal method is to lex (tokenize) the input file first, which is what I'm doing with Scanner.  Then build a [parse tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree) as you lex, which is what I assumed you wanted to do.  Then walk the parse tree to interpret or compile your code.

Comment: Your title is extremely confused. You appear to want to parse what are commonly called "S-expressions" in the LISP world; this takes a (simple but) context-free grammar.   You cannot parse such expressions with regexps.   Time to learn about real parsers.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2336769/120163

Comment: @markspace:  "build a parse tree as you lex..."  This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Ok, I got it, I'm forced to parse per character (since scan.next() may give invalid tokens such as "(GET" which I would be forced to parse again to get valid tokens ). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I understood thanks to Ira Baxter that this context free grammar can't be parsed with RegExp and I used the concepts of S-Expressions to build up the interpreter, whose source code you can find [here](https://github.com/fedexist/Expression-Intepreter). If you have any question about it (mainly because the comments aren't translated in english, even though I think the code is pretty clear), just message me or comment here.

Basically what I do is:

- Parse every character and tokenize it (e.g '(' -> is OPEN_PAR, while "SET" -> STATEMENT_SET or a random letter like 'b' is parsed as a VARIABLE )
- Then, I use the token list created to do a syntactic analysis, which checks the patterns occuring inside the token list, according to the grammar
- If there's an expression inside the statement, I check recursively for any expression inside an expression, throwing an exception and going to the following correct statement if needed
- At the end of analysing every single statement, I compute the statement as necessary as for specifications

Answer (score 1):

Solution proposed by [Ira Braxter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120163/ira-baxter):

> Your title is extremely confused. You appear to want to parse what are commonly called "S-expressions" in the LISP world; this takes a (simple but) context-free grammar. You cannot parse such expressions with regexps. Time to learn about real parsers.

---

> Maybe this will help: [stackoverflow.com/a/2336769/120163](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336769/120163)